# Endless for-loop when start variable gets the value from a bool variable

Tags: php

I have this very simple MCVE for PHP 7.2.11:

```
$loopStart = 150  < 100 + 15;
for ( $count = $loopStart ; $count < 3 ; $count++ )
{
    echo sprintf( "count=%d<br>", $count );
}
die("finished");
```

Running the script I am expecting this output:

```
count=0
count=1
count=2
finished
```

Executing this script results in an ***endless*** loop where `$count` **NEVER** gets incremented.

Changing the first line to `$loopStart = intval(150 < 100 + 15);` works --> the for-loop iterates 3 times and then it ends.

Do I miss something or is this a very funny PHP bug? It looks to me that PHP has a serious problem with the origin assignment where the result is `bool` but - especially PHP - is known for a very relaxed implicit type casting.

PHP does **NOT** increment `$count` and this must not be - regardless what type [`bool` or `int` or `float`] the initial variable has.

Comment: `false` is always less than `3`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver It enters the loop and `$count` is never incremented. Please run the MCVE to understand what I am talking about. Your comment has nothing to do with my question Sir.

Comment: See also: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php → `++` behaviour is undefined for booleans. Wheras a real arithmetic operation `+=1` works on false.

Comment: The assignment of `$loopStart` is not a bool it is empty/null without the use of intval.

Comment: @mario Please write it as answer. In the link is in the text this remark: _Incrementing or decrementing booleans has no effect._ - this is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual doesn't [mention it](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) very explicitly.  But `++` is simply undefined for booleans. Whereas a real arithmetic operation `(false + 1)` does indeed increment to `true`.

More specifically look at [`zend_operators.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c#L2424)

- It simply doesn't do anything for `IS_BOOLEAN` vars.
- Like it ignores arrays and a few other types.

You wouldn't be mistaken if you though it worked. Because you know, it did. In PHP3.

Comment: Thank you mario! It is mentioned below Example #1. You are right - This note could be at the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 0):

`$loopStart = 150  < 100 + 15;` evaluates to `false` so does `$count`.  `$count++` evaluates to `false` and `false` is always less than `3`:

```
$loopStart = 150  < 100 + 15;
for ( $count = $loopStart ; $count < 3 ; $count++ ) {
    var_dump($count);
    var_dump($count < 3);
    var_dump($count++);
    exit;
}
```

Yields:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

See https://3v4l.org/rMECJ

Comment: No, this is not the correct answer. User [mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario) wrote the correct reason.

Comment: That was a comment not an answer and yes it is correct as you can clearly see if you run it.

Comment: The reason is this - as stated in the documentation to which mario referred: _Incrementing or decrementing booleans has no effect._